# Ajax Odometer with Prototype?

Tags: javascript, ajax, prototypejs, counter

I saw the cool AJAX odometer on http://odesk.com and thought it could be quite useful to have something similar for one of my sites.  I came across this code that is similar (http://tools.uvumi.com/odometer.html), but it is for Mootools and I use Prototype on all of my sites.  I'm wondering if something like this has been made to work with Prototype?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not that I know of. But Mootools and Prototype have *very* similar APIs, so you could probably port it over quite easily. For example:

```
window.addEvent('domready',this.domReady.bind(this));
```

would become:

```
document.observe('dom:loaded', this.domReady.bind(this));
```

Some other parts would be trickier, but the [Prototype/script.aculo.us mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/prototype-scriptaculous) would be happy to help you out.